# how to mock ApolloProvider when testing react with Jest

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jestjs, apollo-client

I am trying to test my React & graphql code. when trying to mock the *ApolloProvider* with the *MockedProvider* from @apollo/react-testing (as written in the documentation of Apollo), i am getting this error:

[image]

it seems that it cannot find the "client" object of the *ApolloProvider*. the thing is: the idea behind *MockProvider* is configuring the request & result within a prop called 'mocks', and in this way cancel the need for the 'client' object, right? 
not sure why i am getting problems regarding the 'client' object when im using the *MockProvider*?

**Versions**:
"@apollo/react-testing": "^3.1.3",
"apollo-client": "2.4.5",
"react-apollo": "2.2.4",

**THANKS!!!**